# How to add classes or styles to inline elements via Redactor-API

Tags: redactor

I can't figure out how you to use Redactors *this.inline*. I want to add a class to a anchor element. Suppose my cursor is inside the anchor and I do *this.inline.toggleClass('foo')* it will add a span inside the anchor with class *foo*. If I select the anchor text and do *this.inline.format('a', 'class', 'foo')* it will remove the anchor tag completely. If I select some text and do *this.inline.format('a', 'class', 'foo')* it will add a span with class *foo* but not the anchor tag :(

How are you supposed to add classes or styles to selected text or inline element under the cursor?